# unable to make multiple comments on insert for some reason

Tags: php, sql-insert

I have made a comment section for my gallery , but not sure sure why  only able to do 1 comment on it then it wont allow me to execute any more comment on that item

the insert

```
public function insertComment() {
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $this -> sanitizeInput();   
    }        
    extract($_POST);

    $name = $_SESSION['userName'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $productID = $_GET['id'];

    echo $name;
    echo $comment;
    echo $productID;


    $qry = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$comment', '$productID' )";

    $rs = $this -> db -> query($qry);

    if($rs && $this -> db -> affected_rows > 0) {
        $msg = 'comment record created. ';
        } else {
        echo 'Error inserting comment';
    }
    return $msg;      
}
```

tables

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None    auto_increment                          
    name    varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                 
    comment varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                 
    productID   int(11)         No  None
```

Comment: Don't ever use `extract()`. it's a sign of extremely lazy coding, and replicates much of the greater extraordinary stupidities built into php. namely: register_globals. You're also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Where have you seen the `extract` stuff? It's really oooold technique considered insecure since ~15 years. Note that a hacker can overwrite variables in your script by adding fields to the post. Should not beeing used!

Comment: Maybe a unique index on productID ?

Comment: get_magic_quotes_gpc , extract !!! you have greater things to worry about than your bug `...

Comment: Do not insert NULL as id, instead specify the columns you want to insert in your INSERT statement: INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, productID) VALUES (?, ?, ?) - and use PDO.

Comment: oh the santaize input has escape magic quotes for ssl injection threats

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, productID) VALUES ('$name', '$comment', '$productID' )";
```

remove the null